# Creating line offsets/buffers in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology, line, representation

[image]I have line segments with values of obstacles (buildings, trees, etc) in both sides, how can I represent them according to these values? E.g. in one segment the right has 45° while the left only 5°, so the end line must have a bigger offset/buffer to the right.

Im working in ArcGIS 10

Comment: I just upload a picture, as you can see some sides are bigger than others

Comment: Have you tried to use buffer's Side type parameter? see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

There an easy solution within the buffer tool. Just use your left obstacle field value I(LeftO in the image below) as distance field, and choose side type == LEFT.

[image: Buffer tool]

The problem however is using the left/right terminology. A road direction is determined by the relative location of the end point to its starting point. Namely by the direction the road was digitized. See my example below in which I have digitized from North to South (see arrow for digitization direction):

[image: North to South digitization]

If you don't know how the data was digitized, you will not be able to predict your results. Thus a pre-processing step would be to [flip direction of lines](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/flipping-lines.htm) in order that all lines will be directed to the same direction.
Than you can use the tool with full confidence about the expected results.